# Change rotation of vertical gauge in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, gauge

I add a vertical gauge which counts from 0 to 100. It works perfectly however it moves from bottom to top. Is there a way to change rotation of it? There is no any setting for that in gauge class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a vertical slider as a work around?

Comment: Using a vertical slider is a really good idea. Thank you very much.